# Race conditions with java references

Tags: java, multithreading, reference, atomicreference

The atomic integer, long, boolean etc are used to do any atomic updates to the respective types since there may be a race condition when we execute any manipulation on them, e.g ++. But what are the different cases with references where there may be such race conditions?

Best Regards,
Keshav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK references are not subject to race condition because the JVM guarantees that the reference update is an atomic operation (unlike e.g. updating a `long`, where the lower and upper 4 bytes are updated in two distinct steps). The only critical case, as SLaks noted, is `compareAndSet` which is not atomic by nature. That is very rarely used with native references, but it is a known idiom with `AtomicReference` when there is a need to update two (or more) logically codependent variables at once. *Java Concurrency in Practice*, section 15.3.1 publishes an example for this, using an `AtomicReference` to update two variables (stored in a simple class) in one atomic operation.

The main reason for the existence of `AtomicReference` - apart from consistency of interfaces - is *visibility* and *safe publication*. In this sense, an atomic variable is a "better `volatile`".

Answer (score 2):

Operations like `++` are subject to race conditions because they involve multiple discreet operations (fetch, increment, store).

Setting a reference (`a = b`) is a single operation and is thus not subject to race conditions.

Operations on reference types (`a.someMethod()`) can do anything they want to and may or may not be subject to race conditions.

Comment: then why do we have a class AtomicReference

Comment: @keshu: `compareAndSet` is subject to race conditions because it involves two operations.

Answer (score 0):

For learning purpose i wrote a ConcurrentLinkQueue using AtomicReference.

```
      package concurrent.AtomicE;

      import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

     public class ConcurrentLinkQueue<V> {
       private final AtomicReference<Node> firstNodePointer = new AtomicReference<Node>();

   public void fastOffer(final V data){
    final Node<V> newNode = new Node<V>(data,Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.out.println(newNode);
    AtomicReference<Node> pointer = firstNodePointer;
    for(;;){
        if(pointer.get() == null){
            if(pointer.compareAndSet(null,newNode)){
                return;
            }
        }
        pointer = pointer.get().getNext();
    }
}

private static class Node<V>{
    private AtomicReference<Node> next = new AtomicReference<Node>();
    private volatile V data = null;
    private String threadName = "";

    Node(V data1,String threadName){
        this.data = data1;
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "threadName=" + threadName +
                ", data=" + data;
    }

    private AtomicReference<Node> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    private void setNext(AtomicReference<Node> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    private V getData() {
        return data;
    }

    private void setData(V data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```